# Rails 4 AbstractController::Metal rendering with status != 200 (i.e. 401, 404)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, render, rack

I'm implementing a simple API in my application to communicate with an Android application. I'm trying to use AbstractController::Metal mainly for performance. The problem I'm having is that render is ignoring the status option that I'm passing.

Very simple example:

```
class Api::V1::ApiController < ActionController::Metal
  include AbstractController::Rendering
  include ActionController::Renderers::All
  include ActionController::RackDelegation
  include ActionController::MimeResponds
end

class Api::V1::SessionsController < Api::V1::ApiController
  def show
    render status: :unauthorized   # using 401 yields the same result
  end
end
```

Calling

```
curl -v -X GET http://app.dev:3000/api/v1/sessions.json
```

I'd expect to receive a 401 but instead I get a 200 OK:

```
> GET /api/v1/sessions.json HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: app.dev:3000
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Any ideas? Overwriting response.status is the only work around I've found so far, but honestly it looks like an ugly hack.

Thank you in advance for your insights.

Comment: are you sure that `/api/v1/sessions.json` goes to your action `show` action? and also looks like instead of `render status: :unauthorized` should be `render nothing: true, status: 401`

Comment: @IS04 Yes it goes to show because in my routes I have resource :sessions (instead of resource**s**). I've also tried render nothing and got the same result (regarding the status, the response's body was empty).

Comment: I'm having the same problem with ActionController::Metal -- any insights you uncovered on it?

Comment: @Michael No, I'm overwriting response.status :(

Comment: @FelipeKoch Okay, good to know. Sad that it has to come to that.

Comment: Check out the solution for the issue here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70998414/7674579

Answer (score 1):

To render nothing and return code `401` use:

```
render nothing: true, status: :unauthorized
```

Answer (score 0):

use `head`
[ActionController::Head](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Head.html)

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Api::V1::ApiController
  def show
    head :unauthorized
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the example code shown below. This was working with `ActionController::Metal` in **Rails 3**, and started failing after upgrading to **Rails 4.2.4**:

```
# config/routes.rb
get :unauthorized, to: 'unauthorized#respond'     

# app/controllers/unauthorized_controller.rb
class UnauthorizedController < ActionController::Metal
  def respond
    head :forbidden
  end
end

# spec/controllers/unauthorized_controller_spec.rb
describe UnauthorizedController do
  it 'should respond with 403 forbidden' do
    get :respond, {}, {}

    expect(response.status).to be == 403
  end
end
```

The test was failing after the upgrade. So to solve this I had to change

`class UnauthorizedController < ActionController::Metal`

to

`class UnauthorizedController < ActionController::Base`