# What module is needed with ActionController::Metal to be able to pass status code to render?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller

I have an Api controller using ActionController::Metal on Rails 4.1.6 like this:

```
class Api < ActionController::Metal
  include AbstractController::Rendering 
  include ActionController::ImplicitRender
  include ActionController::MimeResponds
  include ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection  
  include AbstractController::Callbacks
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods
  include ActionController::Head

  ...
end
```

However, if I put this in an action

`render 'not_found', status: 404`

It renders the 'not_found' template correctly but returns a 200 status code. Running the same render in ActionController::Base, it returns the desired 404. What module am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

try to include these 3 modules in the same order

```
include AbstractController::Rendering
include ActionView::Rendering
include ActionController::Rendering
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
include AbstractController::Rendering
```

with this:

```
include ActionController::Rendering
```

Comment: If I replace `AbstractController::Rendering` with `ActionController::Rendering`, it raises the following error: `NoMethodError: super: no superclass method 'render' for #<ApiController:0x007f8629c64600>`.

If I include both, it renders, but without the status (the original problem).

Comment: Strange. The API doc says `ActionController::Rendering` includes `AbstractController::Rendering` so there is no need to explicitly include both. I reproduced your problem in Rails 4.0.2 and my solution solves it. This might be a bug in Rails.

Comment: I'm on Rails 4.1.6, not sure if they made substantial changes here between versions? Maybe I need to raise the issue with the maintainers and see what they say.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include these modules and you are good to respond with status code and render the response in json format.

```
include AbstractController::Rendering
include ActionController::Rendering
include ActionController::Renderers::All
include ActionController::Rescue
```

And here is the render code:

```
render json: { message: "You request is forbidden" }, status: :forbidden
```